# regular expression conversion Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex, converters

Hey i have the following regular expression `/\(+[а-яА-Я- \)]+/` so I need to use it in PHP how to convert it because PHP gives me error

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 15

I am new to regexp but I don't understand where is the problem and yea those are Cyrylic characters

I need that so I can extract cyrylic characters. You can see that the regexp is working 
here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xSPZX/

Comment: Does it work if you use a range of non-Cyrillic characters? It could be that PHP doesn't understand ranges outside the Latin alphabet.

Comment: You just flipped two characters `\([а-яА-Я ]+\)`.

Comment: I am not sure but i think it accepts non-latin chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$text = "Mon Jul 01 2013 19:27:19 GMT+0300 (Финландия - лятно часово време)";
echo preg_replace('/\(+\X+\)+/', '', $text);
```

Some additional info: [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Comment: This is working and is possible solution for now thank you Teneff :)